# Why is my XML not redirecting with the form action URL?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I am expecting my page will post redirect to the url in the action attribute of the form.
But it's not, it's just keep on response.writing the \n and \t on my page.
I have the AutoSubmit function on my body onload.

```
    Dim xhtmlstr As String
    
    xhtmlstr = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
    xhtmlstr += "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>"
    xhtmlstr += "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>\n"
    xhtmlstr += "<head>\n"
    xhtmlstr += "\t<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>\n"
    xhtmlstr += "<title>Sending request....</title>\n"
    xhtmlstr += "<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'>"
    xhtmlstr += "window.history.forward(-1);"
    xhtmlstr += "function AutoSubmitForm() {"
    xhtmlstr += "document.collect.submit();"
    xhtmlstr += "}\n"
    xhtmlstr += "</script>\n"
    xhtmlstr += "</head>\n"
    xhtmlstr += "<body onload='AutoSubmitForm()'>\n"
    xhtmlstr += "<form name='collect' id='collect' action='https://myURL.net/payment/Default.aspx' method='POST'>\n"
    xhtmlstr += "\t<input type='hidden' name='paymentrequest' value='" + createRequest() + "'/>\n"


    xhtmlstr += "</form>\n"
    xhtmlstr += "</body>\n"
    xhtmlstr += "</html>"

   
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8"

    Response.Clear()
    Response.Write(xhtmlstr)
    Response.End()
```

Comment: That's HTML, not XML. Dynamic generation of HTML is what both Classic ASP and ASP.NET do right out of the box. Why not just create a proper ASP.NET page and bind the extra data? It would be a *lot easier* to troubleshoot an ASP.NET page instead of a dynamically constructed HTML string. For all anyone knows, there could be a typo in that string

Comment: As for redirections, the code doesn't return a redirection result (302) or call `Redirect`.  HTML doesn't cause redirections either, unless you mean navigating to some other page using JavaScript.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the dev from the payment gateway suggested this code lol. should i just create it using the aspx page and pass the values there?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos should the form be posting to the URL in the action attribute together with the value of the hidden input?

Comment: Why don't you create a proper form instead of that string? It's very hard to read - no formatting, no highlighting. Besides, posting from Javascript isn't redirecting. All one can say from seeing this block of text is that it doesn't redirect. If you create a *proper web page* you'll probably find any errors just by looking at it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos a proper form should be posting this to the URL right?

Comment: To put it another way - I'm not going to try to read that. And I bet nobody else will. *Why are you constructing an HTML page like this*?

Comment: Are you trying to perform a POST automatically? That should be very easy to do with a few lines of JavaScript

Comment: Check for example [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes im trying to POST automatically to the URL defined in the action

Comment: Then you need neither forms nor HTML. BTW what happened here is called [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have a problem X (post some data) and assume Y is the solution (inject an entire new page in the existing one? Or another frame? A popup?). When that doesn't work you asked about Y, not X. Which hasn't been explained yet. If you want to display a popup and post at the same time, you can do it easily with Javascript, entirely on the client. No need to create another page

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no this is for a payment gateway. So I'm passing values for them to process the amount and payment using the POST url

Comment: That's not what this code does. It emits HTML to the browser. Which would be easier to do using ASP.NET. As for the generated page - have you tried debugging it in the browser? It contains conflicting calls - submit the form on load *and* go back in a raw JavaScript, that gets executed before the form fully loads. Again, if you used a proper ASP.NET page it would be easier to see what's going on and debug it. You could put a breakpoint in the code to see which line gets executed first for example

Comment: Right now, apart from creating a proper ASP.NET page just for sanity's sake, you can use `console.log` to write to the browser's console and see what's going on. Or you could use `debugger;` to pause execution and go directly to the debugger. Check [How to pause your code with breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints)

Comment: You're kinda hard-headed, aren't you? ;-) Why don't you just take Panagiotis' good advice? Shuck that monstrosity of an HTML string and create a proper ASP.NET page. He's right—we're not going to want to help you when you insist against all good cautions on taking an approach that's hard to read and doomed to fail. Listen up! Ditch that ugly code and do it right. Help us help you.